# Python Tk() Button command not completely working

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I'm quite new to python programming and have quite a basic question which I can't seem to resolve myself - I hope someone might be able to shed some light on this!

I created a `.py` file which runs a basic Rock, Paper, Scissors game between a user and the (random) computer. This uses a GUI via a `tk()` and works absolutely fine.

Then, I created another `.py` file, this time to create an overall menu GUI, from which I could choose to run my Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I can create this `tk()` fine, the button to select the RPS game, the game loads up, but this time it doesn't work at all! I can press the buttons, but they don't progress the game.

Here's my code for the `game.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random

def gui():
    <game code goes in here, including other functions>

root=Tk()
root.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
# more code to define what this looks like
# including a Frame, buttons, labels, etc>

if __name__=='__main__':
    gui()
```

And then I created the overall game menu, menu.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random
import game

main=Tk()
main.title("J's games")

mainframe=Frame(main,height=200,width=500)
mainframe.pack_propagate(0)
mainframe.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

intro=Label(mainframe,
    text="""Welcome to J's Games. Please make your (RPS) choice.""")
intro.pack(side=TOP)

rps_button=Button(mainframe, text="Rock,Paper,Scissors", command=game.gui)
rps_button.pack()

test_button=Button(mainframe,text="Test Button")
test_button.pack()

exit_button=Button(mainframe,text="Quit", command=main.destroy)
exit_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

main.mainloop()
```

If anyone can see something obvious, please let me know. I'm confused as to why it works on its own, but not when I incorporate it into another function (the button command). I've tried the IDLE debugging but it seems to freeze on me!

Comment: One problem is that you are creating two root windows (ie: you call `Tk()` twice). A tkinter program should have exactly one root window.

Comment: Please indent code just once in the write box, so it appears flush left after formatting, so it can be cut and pasted and possibly run without further de-indenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want the main window to remain when one selects a particular game.  That means that the game should be in a separate frame, initially in a separate Toplevel.  Modify your rps file something like the following,

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random

class RPS(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        Toplevel.__init__(parent)
        self.title(title)
    #game code goes in here, including other functions

# more code to define what this looks like
# including a Frame, buttons, labels, etc>

if __name__=='__main__':
    root=Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    RPS(title = "Rock, Paper, Scissors")
    root.mainloop()
```

This way, importing the file does not create a second root and mainloop.

If you want only one game running at a time, you could instead use a paned window with two panes.  Turtledemo does this.  The code is in turtledemo.**main**.  You would then derive RPS from Frame and pack it into the second pane.